# execute injecting logic only in UMD bundle

Tags: reactjs, umd, nwb

I use react nwb toolkit for my lib, I also uses UMD bundles.

So for UMD bundle size optimize, I inject one of components through "script" tag, and this injecting needed only when use the UMD bundle, because in normal lib this lib comes from dependencies.

How I can do this? May be there is some "process" variable, which will "say" it's a UMD build.

[image: code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

umd.js (umd bundle handler)

```
window.isUmdBundle = true;
```

index.js (module bundle handler)

```
window.isUmdBundle = false;
```

component.js

```
if(window.isUmdBundle) {
   // ...code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As nwb allows us to use webpack configuration.
I think a good way is to pass similar to in webpack.config

I would add to nwb.config.js

```
webpack: {
    extra: {
        externals: {
            // Use external version of Jodit
            jodit: 'Jodit',
        }
    }
 }
```